# Web view deprecation issue iOS

Tags: ios, web, view

We were using web view previously in our app so that we received the web view depreciation mail from apple.

So now we completely removed web view from our code and also we don't use WebKit at the place of the web view.

But still, we getting the depreciation mail from apple whenever I upload the build to the test flight.

Note:  We are using Firebase SDK, Crashlytics SDK and fabric SDK.

All pod files are updated.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Did you try a search in the whole workspace?

Comment: use `cmd+shift+f` and search for `UIWebview` in whole project. may be you missed it somewhere else.

Comment: yes, I checked and no UIWebview element in my whole project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any third parties `SDK` which is used `UIWebView` internally, Then no need to worry at all because currently, it is not mandatory. Once apple provide the official timelines regarding the deprecation of `UIWebView` then all SDK required migration.

> In June 2018, Apple announced their intent to deprecate a class called
> `UIWebView`.
>
> Apple did not provide a concrete timeline for implementing this change
> in policy, but with this recent notification, we wanted to make sure
> you are prepared for when it does take effect.

Thank you.